# Google Tag Manager Container Validation Error

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I've received the following error from Google Tag Manager when attempting to preview a Custom HTML tag.

Error Type: JavaScript compiler error

Error Description: Error at line 3, character 4: Parse error. '}' expected

[Google Tag Manager Validate Container Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORAE9.png)

Below is the code included in the tag:

```html
<script>
  (function () {
   <img src="https://jelly.mdhv.io/v1/star.gif?pid=2XlZ2Enj2edTNcGWMlFSwZX2REIN&src=mh&evt=hi">
  })();
</script>
```

Any help with troubleshooting this would is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using an adblocker?

Comment: No, I'm not using an ad blocker in this browser.

Comment: This is not valid Javascript. Also, why are you using a Custom HTML tag? A custom image tag would be more appropriate, plus there would bbe no room for errors.

Comment: Do you happen to remember what this code was for?

Comment: I came here trying to figure out what service this tracking pixel is for because it's broken on my client's site. If anyone else is in a similar boat, I believe it's for Scripps Octane.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to quote your HTML. You may also need to `return` it from the function as well - I've included this.

```html
<script>
(function () {
       return '<img src="https://jelly.mdhv.io/v1/star.gif?pid=2XlZ2Enj2edTNcGWMlFSwZX2REIN&src=mh&evt=hi">'
})();
</script>
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you, much appreciated!